# How to get the matrix logarithm of the rotation

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, rotations

I have the following rotation matrix

$$
R_{sb} = e^{[\hat{\omega}]\theta} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta_1 & 0 & -\sin\theta_1 \\
\sin\theta_1&0&\cos\theta_1\\0&-1&0\end{bmatrix}, \quad \in SO(3)
$$

In the book, it says

**(a)** if $R_{sb}=I$ then $\theta=0$ and $\hat{\omega}$ is undefined.

**(b)** If tr$R=-1$ then $\theta=\pi$. Set $\hat{\omega}$ equal to any of the following three vectors that is a feasible solution.
$$
\hat{\omega} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1+r_{33})}} \begin{bmatrix} r_{13} \\ r_{23} \\ 1+r_{33}\end{bmatrix}, \text{ or } \hat{\omega} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1+r_{22})}} \begin{bmatrix} r_{12} \\ 1+r_{22} \\ r_{32}\end{bmatrix}, \text{ or } \hat{\omega} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1+r_{11})}} \begin{bmatrix} 1+r_{11} \\ r_{21} \\ r_{31}\end{bmatrix}
$$

**(c)** Otherwise $\theta = \cos^{-1} \left(  \frac{1}{2}(trR-1)  \right) \in [0,\pi)$ and $[\hat{\omega}] = \frac{1}{2\sin\theta} (R_{sb}-R_{sb}^T)$.

Since $R_{sb}$ varies depending on the value of $\theta_1$, I'm not able to extract $[\hat{\omega}]\theta$ so that I can get $[r]=[\hat{\omega}]\theta$ where [] indicates a skew-symmetric matrix. I need $r$ to compute $A^{-1}(r)$ where

$$
A(r) = I - \frac{1-\cos\lVert r \rVert}{\lVert r \rVert^2} [r] + \frac{\lVert r \rVert-\sin\lVert r \rVert}{\lVert r \rVert^3} [r]^2
$$

When I choose (c), the matrix has no inverse, Matlab freezes at computing the inverse. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @markvs given a rotation matrix, how can I extract the exponential coordinates of that matrix?

Comment: What are  exponential coordinates of a matrix?

Comment: @markvs $\hat{\omega}\theta$ where $\hat{\omega}$ is the rotation axis and $\theta$ is the rotation angle.

Comment: @KurtG.: The determinant is $1=-(-1)(\cos^2(\theta_1)+\sin^2(\theta_1))$?

Comment: Sorry. Yes. Det is +1.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Terse Notes on Riemannian Geometry](http://www.sci.utah.edu/%7Efletcher/RiemannianGeometryNotes.pdf) by Tom Fletcher, the logarithm of any matrix $R$ in $SO(3)$ is
$$
\log(R)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}~0\,,&\theta=0\,,\\\displaystyle\frac{\theta}{2\sin\theta}(R-R^\top)&|\theta|\in(0,\pi)\,,\end{array}\right.
$$
where ${\rm tr}(R)=2\cos\theta+1\,.$ This worked very well for me in python.

***Remarks.***

1. For $\theta=0$ Fletcher seems to have a typo. It should be a zero $3\times 3$-matrix. Not the identity matrix $I$.
2. If your book says that when $R=I$ the matrix logarithm is undefined then this is wrong. The matrix log of the identity matrix is the zero matrix.
3. In your matrix,
   $$\tag{1}
   R_{sb}=\left(\begin{matrix}\cos\varphi &0&-\sin\varphi\\\sin\varphi&0&\cos\varphi\\0&-1&0\\\end{matrix}\right)
   $$
   ${\rm tr}(R)=-1$ holds for $\varphi=\pm (2k-1)\pi\,,\,k\in\mathbb N\,.$ Fletcher's $\theta$ for such $\varphi$ will be $$\theta=\pi$$ but then $\sin\theta=0$ and the formula cannot be applied. This is really a singular case: for $\varphi\approx\pm (2k-1)\pi\,,\,k\in\mathbb N\,,$ we have $\cos\varphi\approx-1$ and $\sin\varphi\approx 0$ so that
   $$
   R_{sb}\approx\left(\begin{matrix}-1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&-1&0\\\end{matrix}\right)\,.
   $$
   This is a rotation around the axis
   $$
   \left(\begin{matrix}0\\+1\\-1\end{matrix}\right)
   $$
   by the angle $\pi\,.$ (Note that the $x$-axis flips its sign.) Numerically I found it acceptable to subtract a small number `1E-5` from $\theta=\pi$ and apply Fletcher's formula.
4. From
   $$
   R_{sb}-R_{sb}^\top=\left(\begin{matrix}0&-\sin\varphi&-\sin\varphi\\\sin\varphi&0&1+\cos\varphi\\\sin\varphi&-1-\cos\varphi&0\\\end{matrix}\right)
   $$
   we see that $R_{sb}-R_{sb}^\top$ is zero for $\varphi=\pm (2k-1)\pi\,,\,k\in\mathbb N\,,$ which are exactly the problematic cases where ${\rm tr}(R)=-1$ and $\theta=\pi\,.$ Using
   $$
   {\rm tr}(R)=\cos\varphi=2\cos\theta+1
   $$
   we can write
   $$
   R_{sb}-R_{sb}^\top=\left(\begin{matrix}0&-\omega&-\omega\\\omega&0&2\cos\theta+2\\\omega&-2\cos\theta-2&0\\\end{matrix}\right)
   $$
   where $\omega=\sin(\arccos(2\cos\theta+1))\,.$ Experimentally in python it looks like
   $$
   \lim_{\theta\to\pi}\frac{\omega}{\sin\theta}=\sqrt{2}\,,\quad\quad
   \lim_{\theta\to\pi}\frac{2+2\cos(\theta)}{\sin\theta}=0\,.
   $$
   There is probably a way of proving this somehow. This would mean that, for this particular matrix $R_{sb}$ from (1), the matrix log for the singular case $\theta=\pi$ is
   $$
   \log(R_{sb})=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{matrix}0&-1&-1\\1&0&0\\1&0&0\\\end{matrix}\right)\,.
   $$

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is exactly what I'm facing now. I can't come up with a general case for $[\hat{\omega}]\theta$.

Comment: @CroCo . No worries. The family of matrices you are looking at is quite interesting. This method does not produce the matrix log for $\varphi=\pm\pi$. That's a good reason to (re)search further and that's what makes maths interesting. If you just want a Matlab program that works the case $\varphi=\pi-1e-5$ should be as good as $\varphi=\pi$. I tried exactly that in Python.

Comment: I don't think there is an error in the book. Possibly your source writes it differently.

Comment: Does not matter how we write that. Do you agree that the matrix logarithm of the identity matrix is the zero matrix ?